# Is it possible to detect *which* trap signal in bash?

Tags: bash, bash-trap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identifying received signal name in bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256644/identifying-received-signal-name-in-bash-shell-script)

When using something like `trap func_trap INT TERM EXIT` with:

```
func_trap () {
    ...some commands...
}
```

Is there a way in the function block to detect ***which*** trap has called it?

Something like:

```
func_trap () {
    if signal = INT; then
        # do this
    else
        # do that
    fi
}
```

Or do I need to write a separate function for each trap type that does something different?
Is there a bash variable that holds the latest received signal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No documentation hints of any argument or variable holding the signal that was trapped, so you'll have to write a function/trap statement for each trap you want to behave differently.

Comment: thank you. that saves me digging around even further.

Answer (score 109):

You can implement your own trap function that automatically passes the signal to the function:

```
trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        trap "$func $sig" "$sig"
    done
}

$ trap_with_arg func_trap INT TERM EXIT
```

The first argument to func_trap will be the name of the signal.

Comment: +9000: You are using [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) in Bash.  Brilliant.

Comment: It may be clearer to write: `for sig "$@"; do`

Comment: @kevinarpe: That would have to be `for sig in "$@"; do` - possibly clearer, but `for var ; do` is a common enough idiom (to me), that it is just as clear. It also avoids the trap of using `$@` or `$*` instead of `"$@"` that many people fall into.

Comment: @camh, this idiom is completely new to me. Is this feature documented somewhere? I can't find anything relevant in `man bash`, and I don't know what to call it to search for it.

Comment: @markrian It is explicity documented as far as I know, but have a look at "help trap" or the man page anyway. It is just a consequence of how "arg" is evaluated when it is executed. Bash does not document exactly how "arg" is executed, but if you look at the posix shell docs: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/trap.html it tells you is equivalent to `eval arg`.

Comment: @camh, thanks, but I was referring to the `for var ; do` idiom you mentioned. Traps aren't relevant to that, AFAICT. Okay, I think I've just found *some* documentation for this: _"Omitting the in \[list] part of a for loop causes the loop to operate on $@"_, from Example 11-6 in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html.

Comment: @markrian, this is documented in the bash man page under "Compound Commands", where the `for` command is documented, or you can run `help for` at a bash command line where it is also described. Also, in my previous comment (now un-editable), I meant to say "*not* explicitly documented".

Comment: When you only want to trap INT TERM EXIT, you can change `$func` in  hardcoded funtion name, avoiding the shift. Not better, but maybe easier to understand,

Comment: That's a new one for me @kevinarpe, very neat idiom! The complexity vs readability though ... 

Comment: @kevinarpe Pedantically, no currying is involved here. `trap` commands invoke `func_trap` with its sole argument, `func_trap` is used as a plain [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).