# Bash: retrieve signal trapped

Tags: bash, signals

When trapping a signal in bash, how could you then retrieve the signal which has been trapped?

For instance:

```
trap "cleanup;exit $SIGNAL" SIGINT SIGTERM
```

Such that the cleanup function is executed but the script still exits with its "correct" code.

Or is the signal not the correct exit code for an interrupted process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175647/is-it-possible-to-detect-which-trap-signal-in-bash/2175751#2175751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
trap "cleanup;exit 130" SIGINT
trap "cleanup;exit 143" SIGTERM
```

Signal is not the correct exit code for an interrupted process.

- SIGINT: Signal 2 and exit code 130
- SIGTERM: Signal 15 and exit code 143

Comment: Ahh yes, actually that plus [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!