# How to set process group of a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, process, process-group

How to set process group of a shell script ? Also I want all the child process to be in the same process group

I expect something similar to `setpgid()` in C.

Comment: I want to set the process group from same shell script (self).

Answer (score 25):

As [PSkocik points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112755), it is possible to run a process in its own process group, in most shells, by activating job control (“monitor mode”).

```
(set -m; exec process_in_its_own_group)
```

Linux has a [`setsid`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setsid) utility, which runs the command passed as argument in its own [session](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_337) (using the [eponymous system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsid.html)). This is stronger than running it in its own [process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_290) à la [`setpgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpgrp.html), but that may be ok for your purpose.

If you want to place the process in an existing group rather than in its own group (i.e. if you want the full power of `setpgid`), there's no common shell utility. You have to use C/[Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6551778)/…

Comment: Is lack of `setpgrp` utility due to any technical obstacle?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost No. It can be done in most shells with `set -m` (see [PSkocik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112755)).

Comment: Tried to use this to solve [Is there any way to exit “less” follow mode without ^C?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197199/5355) but with no luck. After changing `(…) | less -R` with `(…) | (set -m; exec less -R)` I get no output anymore.

Comment: `set -m` requires a tty which might not exist

Answer (score 16):

I'll answer part of what I understand:

**How to force current bash shell script to be it self process group:**

I put this in the beginning of my bash script:

```
pgid_from_pid() {
    local pid=$1
    ps -o pgid= "$pid" 2>/dev/null | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
}

pid="$$"
if [ "$pid" != "$(pgid_from_pid $pid)" ]; then
    exec setsid "$(readlink -f "$0")" "$@"
fi
```

**Why do I would need this ?**

When launching a program from *an interactive* bash session, it gets its own new process group. But this is not the case if your program is called from a bash script (non-interactive). If your program relies on being the process group owner in both condition you'll need this.

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my soul! I spent a lot of time to achieve my goals and your solution is a cherry on this pie!

Comment: I don't understand why you pass the variable "pid" to your function pgid_from_pid(). Your function is able to read outer variables, and in order to use passed arguments within your function you would need to access them with the common $1, $2 syntax within the function.

Comment: @Jadzia a line is missing, sorry. Thank you for spotting this. Edited.

Comment: Why is the grep call necessary? AFAICT the ps command will not output anything but the pgid.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think Bourne, bash, or zsh will let you do that, but you could do it in perl using the built-in `setpgrp` (note the slight name difference from POSIX). Pass zero as the PID to modify the group of the perl process itself:

```
setpgrp(0, 12345) || die "$!"
```

You might think you could use perl from, say, bash to set the bash process's group (by passing `$$` to a perl script, for example), but I don't think the perl process would be able to modify the group of a process that it didn't fork.

Depending on what you're trying to do, the job control features in various shells may give you what you need, in a different way, like if you just want to detach from the terminal.

**UPDATE:** I think it's strange that this answer has received a couple of down-votes without clear explanation why. My guess is that the downvoters are misunderstanding the question, which is asking how to *change* the process group of the *current* shell. Or perhaps they know how to do a setpgrp from the shell but are keeping the secret to themselves.

Comment: Just checked, an interactive shell runs programs in a new process group. Non-interactive one (like one started by `cron`) runs programs in the same process group (since there is no controlling terminal there is no need to multiplex it between processes). And process group can't be changed using shell built-ins.

Comment: My answer is about changing the process group of the current process. Please be specific about what I said that's incorrect so I can reevaluate it.

Comment: I'm guessing they don't like the perl dependency, but thats not fair to your answer.  IMO and downvote should REQUIRE a comment

Comment: I did not downvote, but please note that this is not an ready-to-use answer of the question. It was not asked how to change the process group of a perl script (;

Comment: Yes, because there is no way to issue a command in a shell and change that shell's process group, comparable to what setpgid() does, as requested in the original question. One workaround is to start a separate process in a different group (see another answer), and another workaround is to use a different tool, like perl or job control (see this answer for both). When a question isn't solvable as asked, it's appropriate to provide near-solutions as workarounds. All the good answers here do that.

Answer (score 7):

If you turn `set -m` on, new processes will be spawned in a new process group, and if they're backgrounded, they won't have SIGINT and SIGQUIT ignored.

```
if  [ $$ = $(ps -o pgid -hp $$) ]; then
   echo already a process group leader;
else
   set -m
   $0 "$@" #optionally with &
   set +m
fi
```

The new processes group of programs run after `set -m` takes over as the foreground process group of the terminal, unless they're run in the background.

The `set -m` is apparently semi-standard, required by POSIX if the implementation supports "User Portability Utilities".
In practice it works on `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `pdksh`, `sh`, `yash`, and `zsh`. `posh` doesn't have it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a late synthesis, taken from several other good answers here, if your intention is to cleanup any spawned subshell processes (even if the script itself is not directly launched from an interactive shell, but from another process, and therefore doesn't automatically becomes its own *process group leader*), relaunching the current script as a new process group leader if necessary.

```
# First, obtain the current PGID, by parsing the output of "ps".
pgid=$(($(ps -o pgid= -p "$$")))

# Check if we're already the process group leader; if not, re-launch ourselves.
# Use setsid instead of set -m (...) to avoid having another subshell in between. This helps that the trap gets executed when the script is killed.
[ $$ -eq $pgid ] || exec setsid --wait "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$@"

# Kill any subshell processes when the script exits.
trap "kill -- -$pgid" EXIT
# Note: If the script only starts background jobs, and that's all you care about, you can replace all of the above with this simple trap:
#trap "jobs -p | xargs kill --" EXIT  # Kill remaining jobs when the script exits.
```

#### Nested commands

Another complication is introduced when one script that does subshell cleanup is invoked by another such script. The process group leadership does not nest; once a script assumes leadership, its lifetime is not controlled any longer by a parent script, so when the parent script gets interrupted or killed, the nested script will linger on. That's not what the user usually wants.

The following script fragments extend the above implementation with a cooperation model, so that only the toplevel script assumes the process group leadership, indicating this to subshells by exporting `$PGID`. If a subshell finds an existing leader, it will not assume leadership itself, and limits its own cleanup tasks to remaining jobs. Other subshells will only be killed once the toplevel script exits. (So this cooperation model works best when one script only invokes one or only few other scripts.)

```
if [ -z "$PGID" ]; then # No parent script has become the process group leader yet.
    pgid=$(($(ps -o pgid= -p "$$")))    # By defining this, we'll be killing subshell processes of this process group when we're done or interrupted. Any children with the same ambition will defer to us.
    if [ $$ -eq $pgid ]; then
        export PGID=$pgid   # We are (already / after setsid) in our own process group, announce our leadership to any children, so that they don't become leaders themselves and thereby decouple themselves from our lifetime control.
    else
        exec setsid --wait "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$@" # Use setsid instead of set -m (...) to avoid having another subshell in between.
    fi
fi

if [ -n "$pgid" ]; then
    trap "kill -- -$pgid" EXIT  # If we're the leader, kill subshell processes when the script exits.
else
    trap "jobs -p | xargs kill --" EXIT  # Someone else is the leader; killing remaining jobs is all we can do here.
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this was the best answer. For some reason the `setsid` technique (yes, introduced earlier) worked for me, when `set -m` didn't.

Answer (score -1):

As @Rob Davis pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6551778/751061), setting process group is not what you want for shells.

Instead you want to use their process control mechanisms. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360275/751061) covers doing this for `sh` on *linux* and *borne*. In short:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Kill all opened jobs on exit.
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
```

This will kill any jobs opened in the backrground (e.g. with `&`).

Comment: This approach is probably viable, but you're doing it wrong. `$(jobs -p)` will force `jobs -p` into a subshell where the joblist will be empty (try `sleep 10 & sleep & sleep & . You'll need to use write the pid-list to and then read it from a tempfile. At least for most shells (ksh and bash manage to avoid the subshell and they also do similar magic for the trap builtin -- your solution should work in these two shells but not the rest).