# Want to change the process group of a pid

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

Want to kill a process of a tree. 
For example, in the `A->B->C->D->E` chain I want to kill process `C,D,E` but not `A` and `B`.

So i use `setpgid(PID_C,0)` to kill all the children of `C` and also `C`.
It works fine for C++.

But the same thing I want to do with scripting. 
Can anyone help me in this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549663/how-to-set-process-group-of-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting how are you sure that `setpgid` kills your process chain, normally `setpgid` function will join an existing process group or creates a new process group. (And its not `C++`)

Anyway following alternative script should work

Pass the process id of your chain's parent process, i.e. in your case its the pid of process `B`

Its recursively loops over the child processes of a given `pid` and signals each child process to be killed with `9 (SIGKILL)` signal, from below-most order.

```
#!/bin/sh

function getcpid() {
    cpids=`pgrep -P $1|xargs`
    #echo "cpids=$cpids"
    for cpid in $cpids;
    do
        #echo "$cpid"
        getcpid $cpid
        kill -9 cpid
    done
}

getcpid $1
```

Comment: kill -9 pid is not working for me .. Suppose  i give "kill -9 pid_C"
then it should kill all the processes under C and also C , where as in my case its killing only C not its children.
So i am using setpgid() to mark all the processes under C (including C) in a group and then killing that group.

Comment: The shell script I provided doesn't call `kill -9` on your topmost process only. Firstly it kills all the below-most children **recursively** then processes one level up until it reaches the process `C` and kills it.