# how to force subshell on level 2 be in own pgid?

Tags: bash, subshell

Command below prints pid of subshell and subshell of subshell:

```
$ ( ( echo $BASHPID )& echo $BASHPID )& sleep 1
[1] 9885
9885
9887
[1]+  Done                    ( ( echo $BASHPID ) & echo $BASHPID )
```

Now command below is more complicated, but it indicates that second subshell is in 'process group' of first subshell:

```
$ ( ( echo $$ $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID ; export BBB=$BASHPID; ps -e -o pid,pgid,ppid,comm | grep -E "$$|$BBB|PGID" | grep -E "bash|PGID" )& echo $$ $BASH_SUBSHELL $BASHPID; sleep 1 )& sleep 1
[3] 9973
2787 1 9973
2787 2 9975
  PID  PGID  PPID COMMAND
 2787  2787  2769 bash
 9973  9973  2787 bash
 9975  9973  9973 bash
```

Is there simple way to create similar command which will show unique number for last row in second column?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that since you are detaching the subshells from the current process (PGID) with the & operator therefore will run on a separate process (new PGID).

Check this ones also: [How to set process group of a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549663/how-to-set-process-group-of-a-shell-script)

Comment: but why first subshell has own PGID and second subshell - doesn't? (and belongs to fist subshell PGID). In other words I want to detach once again from first shell PGID

Comment: Your subshells are nested, the PPID of the outer one is the bash console itself, its PGID is its own one since its detached. I still wonder why the inner subshell does not have its own PGID tough.

Comment: Just realize I didn't answer your question :p