# Bash: How do I make sub-processes of a script be terminated, when the script is terminated?

Tags: linux, bash, subprocess, termination

The question applies to a script such as the following:

### Script

```
#!/bin/sh

SRC="/tmp/my-server-logs"

echo "STARTING GREP JOBS..."
for f in `find ${SRC} -name '*log*2011*' | sort --reverse`
do
    (
        OUT=`nice grep -ci -E "${1}" "${f}"`
        if [ "${OUT}" != "0" ]
        then
            printf '%7s : %s\n' "${OUT}" "${f}"
        else
            printf '%7s   %s\n' "(none)" "${f}"
        fi
    ) &
done

echo "WAITING..."
wait

echo "FINISHED!"
```

### Current behavior

Pressing `Ctrl+C` in console terminates the script but not the already running `grep` processes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Write a trap for `Ctrl+c` and in the trap kill all of the subprocesses. Put this before your `wait` command.

```
function handle_sigint()
{
    for proc in `jobs -p`
    do
        kill $proc
    done
}

trap handle_sigint SIGINT
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! Except that my bash expected `function` before `handle_sigint`.

Comment: I've added `function` to the script.

Comment: Well, here's a problem: when the script is ran on **hundreds** of files, **not all** processes are started at once (which is good). Sadly, this leads to termination of **only a fraction** of processes on `Ctrl+C`. I suppose, **during termination** inside the trap loop, others are getting started. Suggestions? *(Moving the trap and its function before the main loop doesn't help)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/kill-background-process-when-shell-script-exit looks useful. `trap "kill 0" SIGINT` works on my machine.

Comment: Note: the first line of your script needs to read `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`, for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative is using a `cat` pipe. The following worked for me:

```
echo "-" > test.text; 
for x in 1 2 3; do 
    ( sleep $x; echo $x | tee --append test.text; ) & 
done | cat
```

If I press Ctrl-C before the last number is printed to stdout. It also works if the text-generating command is something that takes a long time such as "find /", i.e. it is not only the connection to stdout through cat that is killed but actually the child process.

For large scripts that make extensive use of subprocesses the easiest way to ensure the indented Ctrl-C behaviour is wrapping the whole script into such a subshell, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
(
    ...
) | cat
```

I am not sure though if this has the exactly same effect as Andrew's answer (i.e. I'm not sure what signal is sent to the subprocesses). Also I only tested this with cygwin, not with a native Linux shell.