# How do I terminate all the subshell processes?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a bash script to test how a server performs under load.

```
num=1
if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    num=$1
fi
for i in {1 .. $num}; do
    (while true; do
        { time curl --silent 'http://localhost'; } 2>&1 | grep real
    done) &
done        

wait
```

When I hit Ctrl-C, the main process exits, but the background loops keep running. How do I make them all exit? Or is there a better way of spawning a configurable number of logic loops executing in parallel?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution -- just add the following line at the top of your script:

```
trap "kill 0" SIGINT
```

Killing `0` sends the signal to all processes in the current process group.

Comment: That sounds nice and clean, but I don't understand how process groups are managed. Is it guarranteed that all the background processes I'm spawning, and no other ones are in the same process group as the script?

Comment: Yes, that's the default behavior for process groups. Unless you wrote code that explicitly makes a system call to change one the process's group, you'll be fine.

Comment: @RussellDavis This is so clean, and works very well. I had to add traps to all the shell scripts I spawned from the master script to make this work.

Comment: Any particular reason not to also trap SIGTERM and EXIT like this answer has? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173421/179583

Comment: @natevw It shouldn't hurt anything. The question specifically asked about exiting via Ctrl-C, for which SIGINT is sufficient.

Comment: @natevw, trapping `SIGTERM` will [segfault Bash 4.3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/1337827) which allows trap recursion. The obvoius workaround is to de-register traps in the handler :) I posted [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28333938/804678) in an answer to a similar question.

Comment: Beware, `kill 0` will sometimes kill "parent" processes (in the case that they executed the script without creating a process group.)

Comment: I'm curious how you found this out.  I can't find it in the man page for kill.

Comment: @jmrah, it's in the man kill(2) (manual for system call): "If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process."

Answer (score 5):

One way to kill subshells, but not self:

```
kill $(jobs -p)
```

Answer (score 5):

Bit of a late answer, but for me solutions like `kill 0` or `kill $(jobs -p)` go too far (kill all child processes).

If you just want to make sure one specific child-process (and its own children) are tidied up then a better solution is to kill by process group (PGID) using the sub-process' PID, like so:

```
set -m
./some_child_script.sh &
some_pid=$!

kill -- -${some_pid}
```

Firstly, the `set -m` command will enable job management (if it isn't already), this is important, as otherwise all commands, sub-shells etc. will be assigned to the same process group as your parent script (unlike when you run the commands manually in a terminal), and kill will just give a "no such process" error. This needs to be called before you run the background command you wish to manage as a group (or just call it at script start if you have several).

Secondly, note that the argument to `kill` is negative, this indicates that you want to kill an entire process group. By default the process group ID is the same as the first command in the group, so we can get it by simply adding a minus sign in front of the PID we fetched with `$!`. If you need to get the process group ID in a more complex case, you will need to use `ps -o pgid= ${some_pid}`, then add the minus sign to that.

Lastly, note the use of the explicit end of options `--`, this is important, as otherwise the process group argument will be treated as an option (signal number), and `kill` will complain it doesn't have enough arguments. You only need this if the process group argument is the first one you wish to terminate.

Here is a simplified example of a background timeout process, and how to cleanup as much as possible:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Use the overkill method in case we're terminated ourselves
trap 'kill $(jobs -p | xargs)' SIGINT SIGHUP SIGTERM EXIT

# Setup a simple timeout command (an echo)
set -m
{ sleep 3600; echo "Operation took longer than an hour"; } &
timeout_pid=$!

# Run our actual operation here
do_something

# Cancel our timeout
kill -- -${timeout_pid} >/dev/null 2>&1
wait -- -${timeout_pid} >/dev/null 2>&1
printf '' 2>&1
```

This should cleanly handle cancelling this simplistic timeout in all reasonable cases; the only case that can't be handled is the script being terminated immediately (`kill -9`), as it won't get a chance to cleanup.

I've also added a `wait`, followed by a no-op (`printf ''`), this is to suppress "terminated" messages that can be caused by the `kill` command, it's a bit of a hack, but is reliable enough in my experience.

Comment: The wait + printf method didn't work for me (using bourne shell), but adding `set +m` just after `kill` suppressed the "terminated" message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [job control](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control), which, unfortunately, is a bit complicated. If these are the only background jobs that you expect will be running, you can run a command like this one:

```
jobs \
  | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m/^\[(\d+)\][+-]? +Running/;' \
  | while read -r ; do kill %"$REPLY" ; done
```

`jobs` prints a list of all active jobs (running jobs, plus recently finished or terminated jobs), in a format like this:

```
[1]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[2]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[3]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[4]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[5]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[6]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[7]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[8]   Running                 sleep 10 &
[9]-  Running                 sleep 10 &
[10]+  Running                 sleep 10 &
```

(Those are jobs that I launched by running `for i in {1..10} ; do sleep 10 & done`.)

`perl -ne ...` is me using Perl to extract the job numbers of the running jobs; you can obviously use a different tool if you prefer. You may need to modify this script if your `jobs` has a different output format; but the above output is also on Cygwin, so it's very likely identical to yours.

`read -r` reads a "raw" line from standard input, and saves it into the variable `$REPLY`. `kill %"$REPLY"` will be something like `kill %1`, which "kills" (sends an interrupt signal to) job number 1. (Not to be confused with `kill 1`, which would kill *process* number 1.) Together, `while read -r ; do kill %"$REPLY" ; done` goes through each job number printed by the Perl script, and kills it.

By the way, your `for i in {1 .. $num}` won't do what you expect, since brace expansion is handled *before* parameter expansion, so what you have is equivalent to `for i in "{1" .. "$num}"`. (And you can't have white-space inside the brace expansion, anyway.) Unfortunately, I don't know of a clean alternative; I think you have to do something like `for i in $(bash -c "{1..$num}")`, or else switch to an arithmetic `for`-loop or whatnot.

Also by the way, you don't need to wrap your while-loop in parentheses; `&` already causes the job to be run in a subshell.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and especially thanks for the btw tips. I am not a bash expert, so I write it by googling.

Comment: You're welcome! I know exactly what you mean. I'm not a Bash expert, either, and I was in the same boat as you until about a year or so ago, when I found the Bash reference manual (linked to in my answer). It's totally changed my life, or at least the Bash part of it. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Here's my eventual solution. I'm keeping track of the subshell process IDs using an array variable, and trapping the Ctrl-C signal to kill them.

```
declare -a subs #array of subshell pids

function kill_subs() {
    for pid in ${subs[@]}; do
        kill $pid
    done
    exit 0 
}

num=1 if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    num=$1 fi

for ((i=0;i < $num; i++)); do
    while true; do
       { time curl --silent 'http://localhost'; } 2>&1 | grep real
    done &

    subs[$i]=$! #grab the pid of the subshell 
done

trap kill_subs 1 2 15

wait
```

Comment: I switched to the accepted solution. Leaving this here in case someone finds it useful for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

While these is not an answer, I just would like to point out something which  invalidates the selected one; using jobs or kill 0 might have unexpected results; in my case it killed unintended processes which in my case is not an option.

It has been highlighted somehow in some of the answers but I am afraid not with enough stress or it has been not considered:

"Bit of a late answer, but for me solutions like kill 0 or kill $(jobs -p) go too far (kill all child processes)."

"If these are the only background jobs that you expect will be running, you can run a command like this one:"