# Automatically open website served with PHP built-in webserver

Tags: php, bash

How can I serve and open the website from the current directory in one command with php built-in webserver?

The command used for php built-in webserver is:

```
php [options] -S <addr>:<port> [-t docroot]
```

However this is a running command, so the following command does not work:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 && open 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Purpose is creating a single alias command to open the website in a browser directly after starting the webserver (all from a single command):

```
alias lserve="php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 && open 127.0.0.1:8000"
```

Comment: Put it to the background? `nohup` ?

Comment: what is your desired action to `open`? accessing the server works when you e.g. run `lynx 127.0.0.1:8000`. as `open` just starts a program on a new vt which program is then called?

Comment: you can e.g. run `(php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 &); lynx 127.0.0.1:8000` which starts the srv in the background via a subshell and then the lynx cmd is called connecting to the host just setup.

Comment: The desired action is to open the website in a browser directly after starting the webserver

Answer (score 2):

Run the server in background:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 & open 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Note that I'm using just a single `&` which starts a job in background. This is **not** related to the logical *and* operator `&&`. Bash's syntax does not allow the command that follows the `&` to be separated by a `;`

However, there is still a problem with that solution. Since the server runs in background, you cannot close both the browser and the server with a single `^C`. To achieve that you need to start both commands in a sub shell:

```
(trap 'kill 0' SIGINT; php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 & open http://127.0.0.1:8000)
```

Now you can put that into an alias:

```
alias lserve="(trap 'kill 0' SIGINT; php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 & open http://127.0.0.1:8000)"
```

Comment: Now the question is, how to close the running php server in the same ^C

Comment: I've answered that already - use a subshell. Btw, what is that `open` command doing? Is it a shell script?

Comment: @user2307317 I've added the `trap` command. Using it, all processes get closed together once you press `^C`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363519/how-do-i-terminate-all-the-subshell-processes

Comment: this does not work for me, as the php server keeps running in the background. As soon as you refresh the page, it restarts the process in the terminal.

Comment: Can't reproduce that. Why should a "page refresh" trigger a terminal application to run? Looks like there is an orphaned process still running.

Comment: let me state it simpler: Open activity monitor; search for php; nothing there. Paste (trap 'kill 0' SIGINT; php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 & open http://127.0.0.1:8000); now there is something in activity monitor running under php; ^C in terminal; php still running in activity monitor. when the page which was opened due to the command is refreshed, the terminal reflects and reinstates the original command as never discontinued.

Comment: I guess `the terminal reflects and reinstates the original command as never discontinued.` means just the process is still running in background and, since it was not detached from the terminal, produces output in the terminal. However, I can't reproduce that. Are you using Linux?

Comment: strange.. running iterm2 with zsh on osx latest installment

Comment: Can we find a solution to this together with [PACT](https://github.com/nickodell/pact) ?

Comment: Great:) will await your take on it!

Comment: @strages Propbably we should not use the `open` utility. we should use the browser directly. I'm working on Linux, I can't reproduce how it works (Well I read the man page, and it looks like it will return immediately after starting the browser)

Answer (score 0):

In the sake of helping someone passing here:

> chromium-browser-app=http://127.0.0.1:8000 | php -S 127.0.0.1:8000