# Exit a subprocess with ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, popen

I am trying to write the output of `top` to a file every 5 seconds which I also got to work.

```rb
cmd = "top -s 5 -pid 123 >> top.txt"
p = IO.popen(cmd)
```

However, the problem I have is that I can't find a way of closing `top`
I have tried

```rb
Process.kill('KILL', p.pid)
```

but `top` keeps writing to the output file.
`p.close` hangs but if I `ctrl + c` it does seem to exit the top command as well. But this as this requires me to manually ctrl + c it is not a viable solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the redirection. `>>` is a feature of a shell: it starts the process and connects its stdout to the given file. In order for Ruby to do this, it actually starts a shell, which starts top and sets up the redirection.

So `p.pid` is the PID of the shell, not top. When you kill it, it kills only the shell and top gets disowned, continuing to run under PID 1.

I recommend using [Popen3](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/open3/Open3.popen3) instead and running just `top -s 5 -pid 123` without redirection. This gives you the subprocess as well as its stdout/stderr, so you can manage the output yourself (such as appending it to a file) while being able to kill it.

Alternatively, make a wrapper shell script that runs top with redirection and set it up to kill top when it exits: [How do I terminate all the subshell processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363519/how-do-i-terminate-all-the-subshell-processes) Then have Ruby run that wrapper script.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I thought something like that might have happened. Really stupid question but if I were to use something like `cmd = top -s 5 -pid 123` &
`stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(cmd)` how would I then write the output to my file? And would to output of `cmd` be saved in memory?

Comment: you can loop on `stdout.gets` and `puts` that to a file opened in `a` (append) mode. If you want to do that in the background while your script continues you can do it in a `Thread`. If you're more comfortable with shell scripting I recommend making the wrapper shell script as suggested at the end of my answer