# Simple BASH script to start Redis sentinel

Tags: bash, shell, redis-sentinel

I have this simple script to attempt to start 3 different Redis Sentinel processes that will monitor master/slave Redis processes:

```
# (attempts to run 3 sentinel processes from one script)
    redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26379.conf
    redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26380.conf
    redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26381.conf
# end
```

but of course, this won't actually start 3 separate processes - it will just run the first command in the terminal window and the second two commands won't be run. What is the best way I can run all 3 commands in separate windows from one script? (I also have some other commands that I would like to run from the same script but I wanted to keep it simple for an example.)

I am using iTerm2 on Mac OSX.

Comment: So, you want not only parallel processes, but dedicated windows/screens as well?

Comment: no I am cool with just parallel processes, I don't need separate windows

Comment: one way is to use an applescript, but it might not be the easiest way

Comment: Just append a `&` to the end of each command and each process will go to background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` offers [*job control*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html), meaning you can run multiple jobs at the same time, in background. Use `&` to start a process in background:

```
redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26379.conf &
redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26380.conf &
redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26381.conf &
```

If you type

```
jobs
```

you'll get a list of running jobs. Note that all the jobs will write their output to the same terminal. I guess is what you really want.

If you really want to launch that processes in different windows, you need to start three terminals from your script and set the `redis-sentinel` command as their initial command. I don't know `iTerm` on OSX but I'm almost 100% sure that it offers such a functionality. For the gnome-terminal it would look like this:

```
 gnome-terminal -e 'redis-sentinel /usr/local/redis/sentinel-26379.conf' &
```

Check the man page to get the right option for `iTerm`.

Comment: this is working great, but one more question for you - how do I kill/close all these jobs with one command - I had to do "ps auxww | grep -i redis" to see all the processes in order to kill them one by one. is there a way to cleanly kill them?

Comment: also "$> jobs" and "$> sudo bash jobs" didn't do anything, but your main suggestion seems to have worked great

Comment: to be more specific, the jobs command does work, but even when I opened a new terminal window, it returned nothing (not even "empty list"). "$> jobs -l" didn't list anything either. weird.

Comment: You can kill a job using it's job id, like this `kill %1`.. is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: what I was trying to say was that the jobs command does work, but nothing is listed when I call '$> jobs', my only guess is because the '&' command at the end of each line doesn't do proper work of registered each line as a true job control job?

Comment: I would suggest to install GNU bash. The default OSX shell is quite old.

Comment: I have iTerm2, also GitBash

Comment: Check this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities

Comment: Is there an effective, clean and safe way to kill all the processes that were started by the same script?

Comment: @AlexMills Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/kill-background-process-when-shell-script-exit) help?