# Fork child process to die when parent exits? (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, kill

I'm working with parallel processing and rather than dealing with cvars and locks I've found it's much easier to run a few commands in a shell script in sequence to avoid race conditions in one place. The new problem is that one of these commands calls another program, which the OS has decided to put into a new process. I need to kill this process from the parent program, but the parent program only knows the pid of the parent (shell script), so this process keeps executing on its own.

Is there a way in bash to set a subprocess to die when the parent dies? I've tried to figure out how to execute it as a daemon because I read daemons exit when the parent dies, but it's tricky and I can't quite get it right. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say kill all the background processes when the parent script that started exits?

Comment: Yes! How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you will be needing `trap` command on parent process exit, but am not sure how to use it though.

Comment: Yes, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits but I'm also a bit unsure how to use it

Comment: Exactly what I meant! I think you can try using that command on the parent script and let us know.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I'm confused as to where in my code I should put that and how to implement it. I'm reading more now...

Comment: Got it to work I believe. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Post what you have tried and worked and accept it, so that people can find it useful in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the problem, and this fixed it (except for some pesky messages that somehow cannot be redirected to /dev/null).

```
trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
```

Comment: Add a bit more context on the problem you faced and explain how this command solved it!

Comment: Looks like the source for this answer (which should have been cited) is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173421/1941654 (which also refers to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333938/1941654). `trap - SIGTERM` prevents segfaults due to infinite recursion on SIGTERM. `kill -- -$$` kills all processes in the process group.