# Kubectl port forward reliably in a shell script

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am using `kubectl port-forward` in a shell script but I find it is not reliable, or doesn't come up in time:

```
kubectl port-forward ${VOLT_NODE} ${VOLT_CLUSTER_ADMIN_PORT}:${VOLT_CLUSTER_ADMIN_PORT} -n ${NAMESPACE} &
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Unable to start port forwarding to node ${VOLT_NODE} on port ${VOLT_CLUSTER_ADMIN_PORT}"
    exit 1
fi
PORT_FORWARD_PID=$!

sleep 10
```

Often after I sleep for 10 seconds, the port isn't open or forwarding hasn't happened. Is there any way to wait for this to be ready. Something like `kubectl wait` would be ideal, but open to shell options also.

Comment: What do you mean by not reliable? Can you provide the information behind the env's ?

Comment: you could use nc -vz $ip $port and loop with while, you can use exit code of the command to finish the loop.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I took @AkinOzer's comment and turned it into this example where I port-forward a postgresql database's port so I can make a `pg_dump` of the database:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

localport=54320
typename=service/pvm-devel-kcpostgresql
remoteport=5432

# This would show that the port is closed
# nmap -sT -p $localport localhost || true

kubectl port-forward $typename $localport:$remoteport > /dev/null 2>&1 &

pid=$!
# echo pid: $pid

# kill the port-forward regardless of how this script exits
trap '{
    # echo killing $pid
    kill $pid
}' EXIT

# wait for $localport to become available
while ! nc -vz localhost $localport > /dev/null 2>&1 ; do
    # echo sleeping
    sleep 0.1
done

# This would show that the port is open
# nmap -sT -p $localport localhost

# Actually use that port for something useful - here making a backup of the
# keycloak database
PGPASSWORD=keycloak pg_dump --host=localhost --port=54320 --username=keycloak -Fc --file keycloak.dump keycloak

# the 'trap ... EXIT' above will take care of kill $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script on a daily basis:

- It uses `kubectl` to automatically find the name of the service you're trying to forward to
- By default it takes the port defined in the service and uses the same one locally.
- You can also choose the ports you want to forward from and to (i.e. `service:to:from`)
- It supports multiple forwards using a [neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits) to `kill` all of them when you `<Ctrl-C>` out of the script.

You use it like so:

```bash
k8sf mongodb mongodb4:27018:27017 kafka ...
```

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

declare -A service_map

NS="${NS:=`kubectl config view --minify --output 'jsonpath={..namespace}'`}"

for svc in "$@"; do
    if [[ $svc =~ : ]]; then
        local_port=
        remote_port=
        svc_conf_array=(${(s/:/)svc})
        svc_name=${svc_conf_array[1]}
        if (( ${#svc_conf_array[@]} > 2 )); then
            local_port=${svc_conf_array[2]}
            remote_port=${svc_conf_array[3]}
        else
            local_port=${svc_conf_array[2]}
            remote_port=`kubectl -n $NS get svc $svc_name -o json | jq '.spec.ports[0].port'`
        fi
        service_map[$svc_name]="$local_port:$remote_port"
    else
        port=`kubectl -n $NS get svc $svc -o json | jq '.spec.ports[0].port'`
        service_map[$svc]="$port:$port"
    fi
done

(trap 'kill 0' SIGINT; for svc pf in "${(@kv)service_map}"; do kubectl -n $NS port-forward --address 127.0.0.1 services/$svc "$pf" &; done; wait)
```